# Split table into multiple tables based on 2 columns

Tags: split, powerquery, m

I'm working with Power Query and I need to split the main table into multiple tables. It's possible to split a table into multiple tables based on 2 value conditions?

I have the below table and I need to create multiple tables based on Product and weekday

[image: Main Table]

And the expected outputs look like this:

[image]

Do you know how can I do it? I have multiple products for each day

Comment: AFAIK, a single query can only output a single table.  If you want multiple tables, you will need to create multiple dependent queries.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not possible for one PowerQuery query to produce multiple tables. Onle one table output is possible.

So, you will need to modularise your data.

Start with the Source Table:

- Name: `tbl_SourceData`
- Code:

  ```fs
  let
      Source = Table.FromRows(
          {
              {"ID0003", "7/18/2022", "Mon", 1, 523},
              {"ID0003", "7/16/2022", "Sat", 6, 235},
              {"ID001", "7/18/2022", "Mon", 1, 124},
              {"ID001", "7/4/2022", "Mon", 1, 125},
              {"ID001", "7/15/2022", "Fri", 5, 132},
              {"ID001", "7/1/2022", "Fri", 5, 124},
              {"ID001", "7/16/2022", "Sat", 6, 413},
              {"ID001", "7/17/2022", "Sun", 7, 124},
              {"ID002", "7/15/2022", "Fri", 5, 523},
              {"ID003", "7/15/2022", "Fri", 5, 324}
          },
          {"Product", "Date", "Weekdate", "#Weekdate", "Volume"}
      ),
      fix_Date = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Date", each Date.From(_, "en-US"), type date}}),
      fix_Types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(fix_Date, {{"Product", type text}, {"Weekdate", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"#Weekdate", Int64.Type}, {"Volume", Int64.Type}})
  in
      fix_Types
  ```
- Data:

  | Product | Date | Weekdate | #Weekdate | Volume |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | ID0003 | 7/18/2022 | Mon | 1 | 523 |
  | ID0003 | 7/16/2022 | Sat | 6 | 235 |
  | ID001 | 7/18/2022 | Mon | 1 | 124 |
  | ID001 | 7/4/2022 | Mon | 1 | 125 |
  | ID001 | 7/15/2022 | Fri | 5 | 132 |
  | ID001 | 7/1/2022 | Fri | 5 | 124 |
  | ID001 | 7/16/2022 | Sat | 6 | 413 |
  | ID001 | 7/17/2022 | Sun | 7 | 124 |
  | ID002 | 7/15/2022 | Fri | 5 | 523 |
  | ID003 | 7/15/2022 | Fri | 5 | 324 |

If you check the number of `Product`x`#Weekdate` combinations, you'll see that you'll need to build 8 different sub-queries:

- Name: `tbl_UniqueCombinations`
- Code:

  ```fs
  let
      Source = tbl_SourceData,
      Select = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Product", "#Weekdate"}),
      Distinct = Table.Distinct(Select)
  in
      Distinct
  ```
- Data:

  | Product | #Weekdate |
  | --- | --- |
  | ID0003 | 1 |
  | ID0003 | 6 |
  | ID001 | 1 |
  | ID001 | 5 |
  | ID001 | 6 |
  | ID001 | 7 |
  | ID002 | 5 |
  | ID003 | 5 |

For the purposes of this answer, I won't go through all of them. But you can at least see the process that you'll need to do for each of them.

- Table 1:

  - Name: `tbl_ID003_1`
  - Code:

    ```fs
    let
        Source = tbl_SourceData,
        Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Product] = "ID001") and ([#"#Weekdate"] = 1))
    in
        Filter
    ```
  - Data:

    | Product | Date | Weekdate | #Weekdate | Volume |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | ID001 | 7/18/2022 | Mon | 1 | 124 |
    | ID001 | 7/4/2022 | Mon | 1 | 125 |
- Table 2:

  - Name: `tbl_ID003_5`
  - Code:

    ```fs
    let
        Source = tbl_SourceData,
        Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Product] = "ID001") and ([#"#Weekdate"] = 5))
    in
        Filter
    ```
  - Data:

    | Product | Date | Weekdate | #Weekdate | Volume |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | ID001 | 7/15/2022 | Fri | 5 | 132 |
    | ID001 | 7/1/2022 | Fri | 5 | 124 |
- Table 3:

  - Name: `tbl_ID0003_1`
  - Code:

    ```fs
    let
        Source = tbl_SourceData,
        Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Product] = "ID0003") and ([#"#Weekdate"] = 1))
    in
        Filter
    ```
  - Data:

    | Product | Date | Weekdate | #Weekdate | Volume |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | ID0003 | 7/18/2022 | Mon | 1 | 523 |
- Table 4:

  - Name: `tbl_ID0003_6`
  - Code:

    ```fs
    let
        Source = tbl_SourceData,
        Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Product] = "ID0003") and ([#"#Weekdate"] = 6))
    in
        Filter
    ```
  - Data:

    | Product | Date | Weekdate | #Weekdate | Volume |
    | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
    | ID0003 | 7/16/2022 | Sat | 6 | 235 |

So, Ultimately, you will end up having many different tables available to you:

[image: Queries]

[image: Dependencies]